# Negative beta forced in saturation region of BJT?

Tags: education

is it possible to have a negative value of beta forced in the saturation region of a BJT when \$V_{CE}<0\$?

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Negative Beta is a meaningless concept for practical purposes. You MAY mean Beta when Vce is opposite in direction to usual. If you reverse the polarity of BOTH Vce and Vbe the transistor still has positive beta BUT as FakeMoustache says, the Beta will be lower than usual. (Usually much lower).

Answer (score 1):

And what would be the use of having a negative beta ?

To make beta negative either Ib or Ie has to reverse direction.

But when you make Vce < 0 you're using the transistor in reverse mode, the emitter becomes the collector and vice versa. Remember that a BJT has a NPN (or PNP) structure so it can work both ways. Due to doping concentration differences one mode will give a higher beta than the other way. Then beta would still be positive.

So no, beta will never be negative.